# configure ddclient to return internal ip instead of public ip

Tags: networking, ip, remote

I have setup ddclient on my machine which has a internal ip within the organization. However, ddclient returns the public ip of the organization. Is there a way to tell ddclient to return the internal ip?

Here's my configuration in `/etc/ddclient.conf`:

```
use=web, web=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/getip, web-skip='IP Address'
protocol=namecheap
server=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com
login=mylogin
password=mypassword
myname
```

I have vpn access to connect to an ip within the organization, so I just need to know the internal ip of my machine to be able to access it.

Comment: Why would you setup servers with dynamic IP addresses?  It's also a very bad idea to rely on Internet DNS servers to link to local addresses.

Comment: he is trying to get to his desktop (or similar) via vpn...

Comment: I just took a quick glance at its man page and wonder if you tried setting `use=if`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source](https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/git/ci/master/tree/ddclient) of ddclient, one can see that the "where do I get my IP" strategy can be set via `use` (not an obvious name...). Your configuration uses a webserver (`use=web`) to get your IP, which is of course your public IP. The example in the source reads:

> For example:

```
daemon=5m                   
use=if, if=eth0             
proxy=proxy.myisp.com       
protocol=dyndns2
```

> specifies that ${program} should operate as a daemon, checking the
>   eth0 interface for an IP address change every 5 minutes and use the
>   'dyndns2' protocol by default. The daemon interval can be specified
>   as seconds (600s), minutes (5m), hours (1h) or days (1d).

So if you set `use=if, if=tun0` where the network interface `tun0` has the internal IP of the VPN endpoint (or whatever interface has the IP you want to access), I'd assume it would work.